# undo usermod for root?

Tags: sudo, root, uid, usermod, gid

At some point where I wanted to do

```
sudo usermod -v 1000-1000 USER
sudo usermod -w 1000-1000 USER
```

I accidentally applied both these commands to `root`.

According to the documentation I can undo these commands by using the same options in capitals, but when I try

```
usermod -V 1000-1000 root
```

then I get the message: `usermod: user root is currently used by process 1`.

Is there another way to (un)do this?

Comment: You can just edit manually the `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files and remove the lines that you added with your `usermod` command. Those are the files that your specific commands modified.

Comment: OK thanks! I saw that the effect of my command was that files created by root got different ownership, not 1000 but a different -higher- power of 10. Got extra cautious / scared after that. Thanks very much, will do this and check!